# Handling dataSource based on environment in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I have a service request to be run on different environment (QA, STAGE) and the DataSource of each environment is different.

I have configured the environment endpoint in the `environment option` and so I have to selected the environment in the `drop down` to populate the endpoint.

Accordingly, I need to select the appropriate DataSource as well. How can this be achieved?

At the moment, DataSource is a grid with properties associated to the request.

I am using **SOAPUI NG Pro**. I'm new to the tool and naive to groovy scripting.

Any help would be appreciated.
**FYI**: I tried accessing the environment via `activeEnvironment`. I've added a custom property but I receive NPE.

Comment: You may use `property expansion` for the relative path of DataSource.

Comment: Also would you please post the script that you tried? Please edit the question to add the existing script.

Comment: First try reading the docs! https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/environment-handling.html and https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html#4-Example----Centralized-Endpoint